# Why is the need of pointer to an array?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am new to C programming.
I came to know that pointers can be declared for whole arrays as well.

**int (arr_ptr*)[10];**

My doubt is, whenever we pass an array as an argument to a function, we are passing the address of the array to that function.
So, again why should we have a pointer to an array explicitly?

**Please explain me with an use case, where pointers to an array can be used.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pointers to arrays encode and enforce the size of that array. Pointers to the first element loses that information.

Comment: *"we are passing the address of the function"* - I kinda lost you there

Comment: * "we are passing the address of the array to that function." Corrected.

Comment: Pointers to arrays encode and enforce the size of that array. Pointers to the first element loses that information
-
Agreed. But, I am looking for an use case, where I need to know the size of an array through a pointer.